# GIt - how to create and switch to a branch when I already modify the code?

Tags: git, version-control

I wrote some code while in master, and realize that I am doing some experiment that I don't want to put in the master yet. Reading [this documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), it seems that I should have done

```
git checkout -b experiment
```

Before I even started writing the code. How should I proceed now? I'm afraid if I execute the command above, what happens will be

1. A branch `experiment` will be created (duplicated from master)
2. Git will checkout from this new branch, which means I will lose my work.

How can I commit my current work to a new branch without affecting master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you made any commits?  If not, that `checkout` command will do exactly what you want.

If you have, you're still ok - that command will create and checkout a new branch from your current `HEAD`, not from `master`.  If you want to `reset` master after you create your new branch that's OK too - just make sure the new branch has everything you need first!

Comment: No I haven't commit anything. So my directory will not get overwritten if I do checkout?

Comment: That depends on if you create a new branch to check out or you're trying to check out an existing branch.  Since it sounds like you want a new branch, nothing should change in your working directory.  Even if you *did* want to check out an existing branch, `git` will warn you if it would have to overwrite any files containing untracked changes.

Comment: You should probably check out a good beginner `git` tutorial.  It seems like your concerns would be allayed with a better understanding of how `git` is working.

Comment: @CarlNorum regarding "that command will create and checkout a new branch from your current `HEAD`, not from `master`", if Louis had already committed the work to `master`, wouldn't that mean that `HEAD` in fact points to the same commit as `master`? I know that's okay, but just wanted to make sure the statement was correct.

Comment: @Cupcake, yes that's correct.  That's why I said "if you want to reset `master` after...".

Answer (score 5):

[Carl has the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640958/456814), but I just wanted to add that if the work you did wasn't committed yet, another option would have been to just stash your changes to save your work before you switched to the new branch:

```
$ git stash save
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ git stash pop
```

The first command saves your changes to the stash, and makes your working directory clean. Then you make your branch, and then you remove your changes from the stash and apply them to the branch. Done!

Comment: You don't have to stash if you're creating a new branch.  Just the checkout line will do the same thing as your stash push/pop.

Comment: @CarlNorum I know, but since Louis seemed worried about losing work, I just wanted to show an alternative solution that makes it clear that his work is being saved before he does the switch.